# TimerService that will close auctions

Tags: java, architecture, microservices

I am developing a Vertx-Spring based Java microservice that will handle creation, updates and deletion of auctions. It will also close auctions based on a timer. What are my options on achieving this functionality? Should I use the `vertx.setTimer()` methods to set timer events to close such auctions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* use a scheduled process to change the state of a resource where any time precision is needed, like an auction, because processes cannot generate events with this precision. You should also *not* use a service based timer to change the state of any system level resource, because you'll have a timer for every service, instead of a timer for every resource.

Instead, when you create a new auction you should add a `closed_at` timestamp field. Your backend services should dynamically generate an `is_closed` flag such that `is_closed = now() >= closed_at`. This way your backend services can validate any operations against the auction (bids, cancels, etc...) and your frontend will report the state of the auction, but the closed condition will have millisecond precision and you'll never try to close the same auction twice.

Comment: Hey, Dave thank you for your answer. I have a follow-up question and I hope you can help me. How to design my bidding service to achieve this high time precision? Should the bidding service also duplicate both flags closed_at and is_closed ?

Comment: @BlueInf the `closed_at` timestamp has to be stored with the auction record, in a database. Services that pull that auction record can then dynamically generate a `is_closed` flag. If this flag is generated in different services, make sure that all services are doing the comparison with the same time zone (i.e. UTC)